# Can you inspect Memory without a breakpoint in VS2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is it possible in VS2019 to view what is in memory without triggering a breakpoint?  I want to see the state of things without invoking any behavior because it seems something is changing anytime I interact with my app.  It's an old .net framework app so I can't just use a data breakpoints.

Comment: 1. When VS2019 enters the debugging state, find "Debug" -> "Window" -> "Memory" in the menu bar of VS2019

2. Then copy and paste the memory address to be viewed into the address of the memory window, and click Enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your scenario, there are two things that come to mind.

### Logs

You can use [logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line) to print some information to some output such as the debug output, console, log files, etc.
You can print to the `Console` (or `Debug`) depending on your application type to see things as they happen. You can write to file to *record everything* and check what happened afterwards.

### Memory Profiler

If you want to see details of what's in memory, you can use the [memory profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2019) of Visual Studio to take a snapshot of memory.

Comment: Thanks @Batesias, I'll look into memory profiler to see if it would do what I need.